# Why am I getting an error for my insert statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I keep getting an error about my comma on my insert statement. Any idea as to why this might be.

Here is the error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

and the `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement

```
insert into custflag (cust_no, flag)
  select 
      customer.cust_no 
  from 
      customer, dupaddr 
  where 
      customer.cust_no = dupaddr.cust_no, select cast(flag as int) 
                                           from flag 
                                           where flag_desc = 'Dup Customer'
```

here is the full code of my query.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT flag ON
insert into flag (flag,flag_desc,available)
values ((select Max(flag) from flag) + 1, 'Dup Customer', 1)

create view dupaddr as 
select distinct c1.cust_no, c1.firstname, c1.lastname, c1.company, c1.predir + ' ' + c1.streetno + ' ' + c1.streetnm + ' ' + c1.suffix + ' ' + c1.postdir as fff ,c1.address2
from customer c1,customer c2 
where c1.cust_no <> c2.cust_no
and c1.firstname = c2.firstname 
and c1.lastname = c2.lastname 
and c1.company = c2.company
and c1.predir + ' ' + c1.streetno + ' ' + c1.streetnm + ' ' + c1.suffix + ' ' +   c1.postdir = c2.predir + ' ' + c2.streetno + ' ' + c2.streetnm + ' ' + c2.suffix + ' ' + c2.postdir 
and c1.address2 = c2.address2



insert into custflag (cust_no,flag)
select customer.cust_no from customer, dupaddr where customer.cust_no = dupaddr.cust_no , select cast(flag as int) from flag where flag_desc = 'Dup Customer'
```

figured it out I added the flag to the view and was able to simplify the insert statement. Thank you everyone for your help!

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT flag ON
insert into flag (flag,flag_desc,available)
values ((select Max(flag) from flag) + 1, 'Dup Customer', 1)

create view dupaddr as 
select distinct c1.cust_no, 
c1.firstname, 
c1.lastname, 
c1.company, 
c1.predir + ' ' + c1.streetno + ' ' + c1.streetnm + ' ' + c1.suffix + ' ' +   c1.postdir as fff ,
c1.address2, 
(SELECT cast(flag as int) FROM flag  WHERE flag_desc = 'Dup Customer') as flag
from customer c1,customer c2 
where c1.cust_no <> c2.cust_no
and c1.firstname = c2.firstname 
and c1.lastname = c2.lastname 
and c1.company = c2.company
and c1.predir + ' ' + c1.streetno + ' ' + c1.streetnm + ' ' + c1.suffix + ' ' +  c1.postdir = c2.predir + ' ' + c2.streetno + ' ' + c2.streetnm + ' ' + c2.suffix + ' ' + c2.postdir 
and c1.address2 = c2.address2



insert into custflag (cust_no,flag)
select dupaddr.cust_no, dupaddr.flag from dupaddr
```

Comment: what is the relationship between this tables `customer, dupaddr, flag`?

Comment: What is that last `SELECT CAST(Flag AS INT)` supposed to do? This is the wrong part .....

Comment: You need to **join** the tables `customer`, `dupaddr` and `flag` in a suitable way, so that you can select the two items `cust_no` and `flag` from those joined tables - you cannot use another *subquery* in the place you're using it - doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To make you query work, here is the equivalent code,

```
INSERT  INTO custFlag(cust_no, flag)
SELECT  a.cust_no, c.flag
FROM    customer a
        INNER JOIN dupaddr b
            ON a.cust_no = b.cust_no
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  cust_no, cast(flag as int) flag
            FROM    flag 
            WHERE   flag_desc = 'Dup Customer'
        ) c ON a.cust_no = c.cust_no
```

<strike>*But I doubt `CROSS JOIN` is not what you want, can you tell me how table `flag` is related with `customer` and `dupaddr`?*</strike>

Comment: The flag table simply holds a custflagid, flag(numeric value), and cust_no. dupadder is a view that i created to get a list of all the customers that had a different cust_no but the same address.

Comment: _The flag table simply holds a custflagid, flag(numeric value), and cust_no. dupadder is a view that i created to get a list of all the customers that had a different cust_no but the same address_

Sorry this comment was wrong there is not a cust_no column in the flag table

Answer (score 0):

As I commented - somehow your code is a bit confusing.... it's not clear how those three tables `customer`, `dupaddr` and `flag` are related - they ought to be properly joined so that you can grab the `cust_no` and `Flag` from a single `SELECT` statement.

I don't see how `Flag` is related to the other tables at all - and quite frankly, I don't see why you even need the `dupaddr` table here at all....

So try something like this:

```
insert into custflag (cust_no, flag)
  select 
      customer.cust_no,
      (select cast(flag as int) from flag where flag_desc = 'Dup Customer')
  from 
      customer
  inner join
      dupaddr on customer.cust_no = dupaddr.cust_no  -- why do you need this???
```

or since that `flag` doesn't seem to be related to any of the rows being selected at all, you could also grab this **once** before your statement:

```
declare @flag INT
select @flag = cast(flag as int) from flag where flag_desc = 'Dup Customer'

insert into custflag (cust_no, flag)
  select 
      customer.cust_no, @flag
  from 
      customer
  inner join
      dupaddr on customer.cust_no = dupaddr.cust_no  -- why do you need this???
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
insert into custflag (cust_no, flag)
  select 
      customer.cust_no, (select cast(flag as int) 
                                           from flag 
                                           where flag_desc = 'Dup Customer') 
  from 
      customer, dupaddr 
  where 
      customer.cust_no = dupaddr.cust_no
```